# Nodejs asynchronous filesystem calls vs asynchronous network calls

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous

Why does node.js manage asynchronous heavy filesystem calls in a worker thread, while some networking operations do not use threads but use natively asynchronous APIs in the operating system that allow the main thread to be notified when a network operation has completed without blocking or spinning and waiting for it? Couldn't async filesystem calls be handled in this same manner, and leave worker threads for intensive CPU bound operations that actually need CPU power to compute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodejs uses libuv as its main cross platform library for OS calls.  Libuv has a cross platform asynchronous file implementation that uses a thread pool with synchronous OS file API calls in order to offer a consistent asynchronous file API.  The thread pool is used to make the synchronous OS calls behave asynchronously through the libuv API.

I don't personally know the whole libuv implementation history, but I've read that it made this architectural choice back when OS-supported asynchronous file I/O interfaces were not mature and reliable or didn't exist on some platforms.  I know Windows now has asynchronous file I/O interfaces, but don't know about all the other platforms that libuv supports.  It could also be that the thread pool implementation just works fine so nobody has prioritized any effort to rearchitect it to more modern asynchronous OS file I/O interfaces.

> Couldn't async filesystem calls be handled in this same manner, and leave worker threads for intensive CPU bound operations that actually need CPU power to compute?

Libuv probably could now be rewritten to use OS-supported asynchronous API calls, but the thread pool works fine and is not causing any problems or issues.  Note that the synchronous OS calls being used will block, but they don't spin or waste CPU.  They just block the thread.  So, they're using a thread when perhaps one is not required, but aren't wasting CPU.  And, the use of the thread pool means it's efficiently using threads, not constantly creating and destroying them, just using a pool of them as needed.

You will notice that libuv does use native asynchronous interfaces for networking since those have been available for a long time in all OS's that libuv supports and that was how the original implementation of libuv was architected.

FYI, the thread pool is also used for offering some asynchronous crypto APIs where a non-threaded asynchronous implementation does not exist.  So, the thread pool isn't likely going away anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks! So nodejs uses a pool of worker threads for two particular reasons. The first is to perform CPU intensive tasks (like crypto). The second is to handle some types of asynchronous I/O, like filesystem I/O or DNS querying, because back when libuv was implemented some OSs did not provide asynchronous I/O interfaces for those, so the worker thread in this case really blocks on the I/O task, and a callback is registered to be executed on the main thread, am I right?

Comment: @Centuri0n - Yes, that's pretty much the way it is.  Technically, an event is added to the appropriate event queue on the main thread and when control gets back to that event queue in the main thread, it can service that event and call the completion callback associated with it.